# Laravel many to many relationship using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to create a many to many relationship using Laravel, but I am stuck.

Here's my current table model:

album

```
album_id
name
created_at
```

user_image

```
user_image_id
value
```

albumxuser_image (junction table)

```
albumxuser_image_id (primary key & auto increment)
album_id (FK from album)
user_image_id (FK from user_image)
```

I want to be able to get the album name from albumxuser_image table.

Here's what I've done so far.

Album.php model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Album extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'album';
    protected $primaryKey = 'album_id';

    public function AlbumxUserImage() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('AlbumxUserImage', 'albumxuser_image','album_id','user_image_id');
    }
}
```

routes.php (I didn't use view since I'm making a practice)

```
Route::get('all', function() {
    $albumxuserimage = AlbumxUserImage::all();
    foreach ($albumxuserimage->AlbumxUserImage as $getthem) {
        echo $getthem->pivot->name; // I want to get the name column of the album table.
    }
});
```

AlbumxUserImage.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class AlbumxUserImage extends Model {

    protected $table = 'albumxuser_image';
    protected $primaryKey = 'albumxuser_image_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['album_id', 'user_image_id'];
}
```

Here's the error I get

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::AlbumxUserImage()
```

Comment: Do you have a `AlbumxUserImage` model? Can we see it?

Comment: Why not just get the album name straight from the `Album` model? Why lookup the pivot first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're trying to call `AlbumxUserImage()` on a `Collection` of models instead of on each individual model.

`AlbumxUserImage::all()` is returning a `Collection` of models, which you can think of as an array. You need to iterate over the collection and call `AlbumxUserImage()` on each model in the collection.

That may solve your problem for now, but you seem to not understand how [many-to-many relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) work in Laravel.

#### How you should be doing Many-To-Many

I don't know why you have a model for your pivot table. That is not how Laravel normally handles models with many-to-many relationships. A typical many-to-many relationship with your tables would look like this:

***Models:***

```
class Album extends Model {
    protected $table = 'album';
    protected $primaryKey = 'album_id';

    public function images() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserImage', 'albumxuser_image','album_id','user_image_id');
    }
}

class UserImage extends Model {
    protected $table = 'user_image';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_image_id';

    public function albums() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Album', 'albumxuser_image','user_image_id','album_id');
    }
}
```

***Usage:***

```
// Get all album names through UserImage
$userImages = UserImage::all();
foreach ($userImages as $userImage) {
    foreach ($userImage->albums as $album) {
        echo $album->name;
    }
}

// Get all images through Album
$albums = Album::all();
foreach ($albums as $album) {
    foreach ($album->images as $image) {
        echo $image->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I read the docs before I asked the question but I couldn't understand it clearly. Now I think I got it, thank you.