# Associate a model to a M:M relationship between two other models

Tags: database, laravel, data-structures, data-modeling

I'm revamping my data model for a game that helps teach language, using `Laravel 5.1` for an API. My goal is to allow the user to click a map (let's say they click on `China`), then choose a locale in that country (let's say `Mandarin`), then all levels associated with that Country and Locale will be loaded.

**Notes**:

- I can't just associate multiple locales to one country, because multiple countries share the same locale.
- I can't associate multiple countries to one locale, because each country has multiple locales
- I may want to reuse a map (Chinese level 1) for multiple locales (so I don't need to redo the map, just load in new dialog)

So my thought was to create a new M:M model called `GameLocal` and table called `game_locale_level` so I can connect multiple levels to multiple game_locales by their ID. [But I know `M:M` models are a no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059809/laravel-many-to-many-relationship-using-eloquent). How can I achieve this data model structure then?

---

Game_Locale table:

```
- When I load a game (China), choose which locale to load (Mandarin)
    - ID 1 - Game: 1 (China) — locale: 1 (Mandarin)
    - ID 2 - Game: 1 (China) — locale: 2 (Cantonese)
    - ID 3 - Game: 2 (Taiwan) — locale: 1 (Mandarin)

- Load all levels that are associated where game ID = x and locale ID = y
```

Game_Locale_Level table:

```
- Make a new M:M table: game_locale_level: game_locale_id, level_id which 
  references the above 

    - game_locale_id: 1 (China - Mandarin) - level: 1 (Chinese level 1)  
    - game_locale_id: 1 (China - Mandarin) - level: 2 (Chinese level 2)
    - game_locale_id: 2 (China - Cantonese) - level: 1 (Chinese level 1)
```

---

**Update**: I think `Laravel 5.4` may have what I want, but I'd need to upgrade: [Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> If you would like to define a custom model to represent the
>   intermediate table of your relationship, you may call the using method
>   when defining the relationship. All custom models used to represent
>   intermediate tables of relationships must extend the 
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Role extends Pivot
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->using('App\UserRole');
    }
}
```